# How to import variable names longer than 8 in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am using SAS 9 to import a CSV file. Some column names have more than 8 characters. When I imported, there was an error saying the columns are illegal in version 6 dataset.

Why SAS says it is a version 6 dataset? Even if I put OPTIONS validvarname=v7; at the beginning, SAS still complains the same thing. I have to name columns with more than 8 characters and it seems a stupid restriction. How can I import such a CSV file? Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to import the CSV in SAS? Long filenames shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you please post the first line of the CSV?  And also the the sas code you are using to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think more than 8 chars should be a problem, can you put _ in place of blanks and check that no column name is a duplicate. Also numbers should go at the end I think (so no *3in4fddfd* or so).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other methods available for importing csv data. If you can save the csv in xls format you could try the following:

```
libname try EXCEL 'C:\temp\try.xls';

data imported;
    set try.'try$'n;
run;
```

I think this method allows variable definitions so maybe try specifying the length/format if the variable still causes trouble.